# How to find the total numbers of object created of my class?

Tags: c++, class

For example, I have my class employee. I want to keep record how many employees till date have worked for me. I can make static count variable and add 1 in my constructor. But whenever my temporary object will be created when we pass object in parameters or return object of our class it will add for them too.

Comment: You should be totally fine. Temporaries / copies will use a different constructor than whichever default one you create. So it won't run the code that increments your counter.

Comment: You could add a bool parameter to the constructor, which decides if the counter should increment or not. (Or use different constructors as @Omada suggested)

Comment: There is no problem for a copy constructor to increment the counter, as long as the destructor decrements it.  The counter should indicate the number of active objects, not the number of objects ever created.

Answer (score 2):

Static class member is the right way to go. A few things to be careful about:

- Make sure you overload all constructors. The ones you don't want to support you should explicitly delete.
- Don't forget to decrement in destructor.
- If this program of yours is multithreaded then use `atomic_uint` or provide locking mechanism of your own.

Comment: This will only give me count of active employee. What if I want count of employees from start till date even If they are not active employees.

Comment: Then remove decrement in destructor.

Comment: True, but there is 1 problem, It will add for temporary copies as well.

Comment: Then you need to determine what a temporary copy is. You can have a *proper* constructor that takes several values and creates *proper* objects. If you then assume that temporary objects are created via default and copy constructors, then you simply don't increment in default and copy constructor, only in *proper* constructor.